# Replacing a line of a file using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a Redhat machine which is my remote machine. And in that, there is a line which I have to replace :

```
server 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

to

```
#server 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

I have tried using **replace** module, but I am doing it wrong. How to do it??

Comment: Please add what have you done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `replace`

```
- replace: 
  dest=FILE_PATH 
  regexp='server 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org iburst' 
  replace='#server 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org iburst'
```